# Python lxml soupparser fails with "Invalid PI name"

Tags: python, lxml

I'm parsing a site and the following fails with an error (I'm not able to resolve with Google):

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
# etree.LXML_VERSION = (4, 1, 1, 0)

# www.hbs-info.de /produkte /schweisselemente.html
fromstring(open(r"HBS Schweißelemente.htm").read())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-caba4799682e> in <module>()
      1 from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
----> 2 fromstring(open(r"HBS Schweißelemente.htm").read())

\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\soupparser.py in fromstring(data, beautifulsoup, makeelement, **bsargs)
     31     used.
     32     """
---> 33     return _parse(data, beautifulsoup, makeelement, **bsargs)
     34 
     35 

\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\soupparser.py in _parse(source, beautifulsoup, makeelement, **bsargs)
     77             bsargs['features'] = 'html.parser'  # use Python html parser
     78     tree = beautifulsoup(source, **bsargs)
---> 79     root = _convert_tree(tree, makeelement)
     80     # from ET: wrap the document in a html root element, if necessary
     81     if len(root) == 1 and root[0].tag == "html":

\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\soupparser.py in _convert_tree(beautiful_soup_tree, makeelement)
    153     prev = res_root
    154     for e in reversed(pre_root):
--> 155         converted = convert_node(e)
    156         if converted is not None:
    157             prev.addprevious(converted)

\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\soupparser.py in convert_node(bs_node, parent)
    214         if handler is None:
    215             return None
--> 216         return handler(bs_node, parent)
    217 
    218     def map_attrs(bs_attrs):

\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\soupparser.py in convert_pi(bs_node, parent)
    271             # interpreted it as being SGML style (<?as df>). Fix.
    272             bs_node = bs_node[:-1]
--> 273         res = etree.ProcessingInstruction(*bs_node.split(' ', 1))
    274         if parent is not None:
    275             parent.append(res)

src/lxml/etree.pyx in lxml.etree.ProcessingInstruction (src\lxml\etree.c:79300)()

ValueError: Invalid PI name 'b'xml''
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: Looks like soupparser chokes on the XML declaration (technically, an SGML processing instruction) at the first line of the page. The page is generated by Typo3 and advertises itself as XHTML, so I'd attempt to parse it as plain XML/XHTML using basic lxml rather than HTML using soupparser.